# Traffic light on a timer using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have been asked to create a traffic light that goes through the sequence set using arrays.

I have managed to create a traffic light that works with the user pressing a button every time they would like to change the colour of the traffic light however, I have now been tasked with making it so the user only has to press the button once and then it goes through the sequence automatically using JavaScript.

The images used in the code are located in the same folder as the script.

```html
<img id="Change Lights" src="red.gif" width="36" height="98">

<br>
<button onclick="nxt()" id="button">Change colour</button>
</br>

<script>
  var img = new Array("red.png", "amberred.png", "green.png", "amber.png");
  var imgElement = document.getElementById("Change Lights");
  var lights = 0;
  var imgLen = img.length;

  function nxt() {
    if (lights < imgLen - 1) {
      lights++;
    } else {
      lights = 0;
    }

    imgElement.src = img[lights];
  }
</script>
```

Comment: have you looked into window.setTimeout()?

Comment: @JordanS or setinterval ?

Comment: @Mahi yes, even better.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<img id="Change Lights" src="https://placehold.it/36x98/ff0000" width="36" height="98">



<script>
  var img = ["https://placehold.it/36x98/ffbf00","https://placehold.it/36x98/00ff00","https://placehold.it/36x98/ff0000"];

  var imgElement = document.getElementById("Change Lights");
  var lights = 0;
  var imgLen = img.length;

  function nxt() {
    if (lights < imgLen - 1) {
      lights++;
    } else {
      lights = 0;
    }

    imgElement.src = img[lights];
  }
  
  setInterval(nxt,2000);
</script>
```